# 4.4.4 not in Android SDK manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to do some testing with 4.4.4 and it isn't available in my Android SDK Manager?
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Image of SDK Manager]

Comment: Did you find avd 4.4.4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no problem at you *Android SDK Manager*, you just have to download the *API 19*.
The *API 19* is used by all the *KitKat* devices.

So in *Android SDK Manager* you should download the package below:

> Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

It is going to work for all the *KitKat* (4.4.x) devices, including 4.4.4 that is a patch with fix/improvements from 4.4.

For further, take a look at the developer site about android 4.4:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

Comment: Ok, 4.4.2 is downloaded and working, but a user is having an issue with 4.4.4 that I currently can't reproduce, so I thought that could be the issue.

Comment: @steve It might be problem at the IDE. I have had a similar problem at Android Studio, maybe say to him try another IDE to check if it solves...

Comment: I also had a user having a problem with 4.4.4 can't reproduce in 4.4.2

Comment: Same here.  Has anyone figured out how to access a 4.4.4 emulator?

Comment: @Whatevo, Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Was using the Android SDK with AVD Manager originally, but ended up going with Genymotion who had 4.4.4.